# Where should I look to find Testing and QA talents?

Tags: qa-developer

We are looking to build up a QA and Testing team within our Product Development. We started out by looking for a person with experience both hands-on and as a manager and for a product similar to ours. After a first unsuccessful hiring round we have now focused the search in two areas where we need most support and are looking for two different profiles: a selenium expert and a java test automation engineer. Still we are having very little luck in the job search. Do you know any specific job boards or places where we can find talented testing and QA candidates?

Comment: Dice.com tends to have some decent talent. There is several linkedIn groups dedicated to QA as well that might be a good resource for you.

If you don't mind, where is the position located at? A lot of the people here (myself included) match the profile you are looking for.

Comment: We can't answer the question without knowing where you are.  A  lot of job boards are region-specific, and even for international job boards, some are more popular in one region than in another.

Comment: I agree with Paul, you either go to a job portal and post your requirements there or you can give the contract to a consultancy company which can line up some good candidates for interview. There are plenty of job portals out there you can pick one depending upon your base location.

Comment: Hi very sorry for the late reply! The job is located in Switzerland.

Comment: Any consultancy companies that are specialized on testing and QA? Location is Switzerland.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I help run and moderate the site...

Software Testing Club has a jobs board - [here](http://www.ministryoftesting.com/jobs/)

Comment: Thanks! I looked into it and I will defintely post the job descriptions there.

Answer (score 1):

Meet with real people in meatspace. Find a meetup in area for relevant technology/language, give 2-minute pitch about positions. Possibly even sponsor pizza or soda for participants. This way, you can reach to people who don't actively look for new jobs.

You may also consider researching possible answers to this question in workplace exchange - about finding/hiring good job candidates: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Peter. Idea worth following up. Unfortunately we have no meetup area but dedicated events. Will see if we can reach out and connect to people in a more informal way.